# How do I fix teeth error bottom and fix the eye rigs?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I'm try to fixing the rig correct. I try to figure out how to fix the teeth inside the mouth and I want eyes to follow it well and smooth. I have not much learn about about rigging or weight paint. I'm a beginner.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rigify rigs eyes are supposed to be a separate mesh (if not, select an eye in edit mode and press P to separate it from the rest). Then select the eye, shift select the armature, activate the 30th bone layer, select the MCH-eye bone (the only one which has a little target bone on its tip) and press Ctrl p > Bone.

[image]

The same applies to teeth, in this case you can directly parent them to the teeth control bones which are in the layer number 0 (Face bone layer).

[image]